# Create a regex to grab image value from node in umbraco

Tags: c#, string, umbraco

I'm trying to get the image from a node in umbraco using

```
var image = node.GetProperty("postImage").Value;
```

however I am getting

```
"{\r\n  \"focalPoint\": {\r\n    \"left\": 0.5,\r\n    \"top\": 0.5\r\n  },\r\n  \"src\": \"/media/8354/Image123Test.jpg\",\r\n  \"crops\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"alias\": \"blogPost\",\r\n      \"width\": 200,\r\n      \"height\": 200\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"alias\": \"thumbnail\",\r\n      \"width\": 50,\r\n      \"height\": 50\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"alias\": \"featuredImage\",\r\n      \"width\": 320,\r\n      \"height\": 238\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}"
```

returned.

Is it possible to come up with regex that will just return "/media/8354/Image123Test.jpg\" ?

thanks,

Comment: a) `node` is a variable name, so we have no idea what type that is. b) that value looks like a string in JSON format, so I wouldn't use regex; just parse the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this.  It searches for `\"src\": \"` and takes everything until the next `\"`

```
    string test = "{\r\n  \"focalPoint\": {\r\n    \"left\": 0.5,\r\n    \"top\": 0.5\r\n  },\r\n  \"src\": \"/media/8354/Image123Test.jpg\",\r\n  \"crops\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"alias\": \"blogPost\",\r\n      \"width\": 200,\r\n      \"height\": 200\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"alias\": \"thumbnail\",\r\n      \"width\": 50,\r\n      \"height\": 50\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"alias\": \"featuredImage\",\r\n      \"width\": 320,\r\n      \"height\": 238\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}";
    string regx = "(?<=\\\"src\\\": \\\").+(?=\")";

    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match mat = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(test, regx);
```

Comment: Just use the right Umbraco method instead of fetching the raw json string

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using the image cropper data type in Umbraco. You shouldn't need to parse the JSON yourself, Umbraco has built in utilities for this.

Try (in Umbraco 7.3.5+):

```
// Where "node" is IPublishedContent.
// "blogpost" is the alias of your crop setting.
// "Url" is of type System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper

IHtmlString imageUrl = Url.GetCropUrl(node, "postImage", "blogpost");
```

This will get the image at the width, height and centring which you specified in Umbraco for that crop setting alias.

There alre also further overloads in the `.GetCropUrl` method which let you specify the width and height in your code.

Checkout the documentation [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/image-cropper#mvc-view-example-to-output-a-banner-crop-from-a-cropper-property).

Comment: This is the only correct answer in my opinion, you shouldn't have to parse json or do string manipulations on the output. If Umbraco decides in a future version the format of the json changes, you're in for a lot of tedious refactoring. Use the Umbraco framework for what it's build for.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the media item, the umbracoFile may be stored as JSON or just the path. For that reason, I created these two little methods to ensure I always get the file path.

```
private static string GetServerFilePath(IMedia mediaItem, bool isNew)
{
    string filePath = (string)mediaItem.Properties["umbracoFile"].Value;
    if (!isNew || filePath.Contains("{"))
    {
        filePath = GetExistingFilePath(filePath);
    }
    return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath);
}

private static string GetExistingFilePath(string filePath)
{
    var jsonFileDetails = JObject.Parse(filePath);
    string src = jsonFileDetails["src"].ToString();
    filePath = src;
    return filePath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like a json. So, you can parse this string as Json and retrive value from key "src". For example, you can use Newtonsoft.Json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
...
string json = node.GetProperty("postImage").Value;
var parsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);
var srcValue = parsedJson.Properties().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == "src")?.Value;
```